# Firebase serviceAccount not read

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble getting my project id and other keys in Java with the Firebase Admin SDK. I want to set up the realtime database, however, after reading the `serviceAccount.json` file, I do not have my project id, and I can't read data from my database.

This is my code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fileInputStream)).setDatabaseUrl("<LINK TO DB>").build();

        System.out.println(" " + options.getProjectId());
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Probleem bij het laden van serviceaccount");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

    ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            System.out.println("data" + mutableData.getValue().toString());
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Complete?" + b);
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?